# Unable to log into Google account when launching Chromium from the command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, chrome

essentially the meat of my question revolves around launching Chromium from the terminal.

If I launch Chromium through the GUI I can log into my Google account just like normal, although if I try to launch Chromium via the command `chromium-browser` and try to authenticate, I get the message "Something went wrong Sorry, something went wrong there. Try again." with no further information.

I have tried to install Chromium with the [`.deb`](https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb) and the [`.zip`](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/dl/Linux_x64?type=snapshots) (with the commands updated for the proper path), I have also followed [these instructions](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys) with no success from anything.

I have also tried launching the regular Chrome browser from the command line with the command `google-chrome` and I am able to authenticate like normal.

This is on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Any ideas?

Comment: In first paragraph, what browser? in 2nd paragraph is the error message a translation? Did one of them use a different configuration? I use the option `--user-data-dir=`, to get more than one profile at a time.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor The first paragraph is an error on my part, I meant "terminal" instead of browser. I didn't use any configuration or flags other than what I said in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

remove "Login Data" & "Login Data-journal" files from ~/.config/chromium/System Profile/
That solved it for me